# How to change the color of html td element after postback in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. On `td` element on click event, I am passing its `id` to code behind page using postback. After postback, I want to apply background color to this `td` element.

Here is my code,

```
<table class="window_month" style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
      <tr id="NavMonth">
          <td id="m1" onclick="">
            Jan
          </td>
          <td id="m2" onclick="">
            Feb
          </td>
       </tr>
  </table>

$('.window_month td').on('click', function () {
        var idName = this.id;
        var selectedid = idName.substring(1);
        $('#hidden').val(selectedid);
        __doPostBack(idName, '');
});
```

How can I apply some css effects after postback here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do several things.

Solution 1:

While your code behind is being executed in response to the call to `__doPostBack(...)`, add a startup script that will set the color of the cell via JavaScript/jQuery. You can add a startup script by calling `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`. The script you register must contain a way to get a hold on the cell that was clicked.

Solution 2:

If the clicked cell's color is the only thing that needs to change on the page, you can also do it with ajax instead of `__doPostBack()`. As you already have jQuery on the page, you can use `$.post()` to call a server side handler or static page method that performs the server side work, and in the `$.post()` function's success callback, you can just change the cell's color using jQuery.

Comment: Consider [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to make it more readable.  I suggest making code stand out by using the code blocks (you can use the back tick`).